# Inserting 1000 results in my database. Automatically

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm building a small application that will work like a phone agenda. I don't think that is really usefull for internet users, but I'm doing it just to learn a bit of php and mysql.

Right now, I'm on the part where I want to check and improve the performance of my data base. For that I would like to add ~ 1.000 contacts to be able to test some indexes and to get relevant results.

I would like to tell me if that is possible and how would you recommend me to do it.
In my database I have: `id (autoincremented) | email (pk) | name | sex | school`

```
require_once("connection.php");
$sql = "INSERT INTO contacts(id,email, name, sex, school) VALUES ";
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
    $sql .= "('".$id1[$i]."','".$email[$i].","male", "Computer Science"),";
}
rtrim($sql, ',');



$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql); 
if ( false===$sql ) { 
printf("error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con)); 
}
```

I have one problem with that! My email need to be unique since is a PK. I want something like 1blablabla@gmail.com, 2blablabla@gmail.com, 3blablabla@gmail.com. Any ideea how to do it?

Comment: Why dont you use the $i and prepend the emailid value with that value?

Comment: No need to insert `id` because its an auto increment field.

Comment: prefix it with the index? `"$i.$email[$i]"`

Comment: Wait, you have an auto-incremented `id` column yet it isn't the PK? That's not going to do you any favours. Add a unique constraint to `email`, sure but keep `id` as the PK

Answer (score 3):

First off, I would recommend using [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) instead of a `mysqli_query` call, prepared statements are awesome for this type of work.

When it comes to the email being unique, just concat a string with the index of the loop:

```
$email = $i . "blablabla@gmail.com";
```

And they will be:
0blablabla@gmail.com
1blablabla@gmail.com
===>
999blablabla@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

A prepared statement would make this very easy

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO contacts(email, name, sex, school) VALUES (?, ?, 'male', 'Computer Science')");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $name);

for ($i = 1; $i <= 1000; $i++) {
    $email = "user{$i}@example.com";
    $name = "Test Name $i";
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

I would also set the primary key on the `id` column and add a unique constraint to `email`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
require_once("connection.php");
$sql = "INSERT INTO contacts(id,email, name, sex, school) VALUES ";
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
    $sql .= "('".$id1[$i]."','".$i.$email[$i].","male", "Computer Science"),";
}
rtrim($sql, ',');



$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql); 
if ( false===$sql ) { 
printf("error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con)); 
}
```

Comment: What is your solution?

Comment: replaced `$email[$i]` to `$i.$email[$i]`, it will be 0blablabla@gmail.com, 1blablabla@gmail.com and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. This will help you to have unique values for each rows and so you can perform various tests on this data without any confusion.

I have used `mysqli_` object type querying. You can use the one you prefer instead.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
    $email = $db->escape_string('email'.$i.'@example.com');
    $name = $db->escape_string('Person Name '.$i);
    $gender = array("male","female");
    $sex = $db->escape_string($gender[array_rand($gender,1)]);
    $school = $db->escape_string('School Name '.$i);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO contacts(id, email, name, sex, school) VALUES ('', '$email', '$name', '$sex', '$school')";
    if(!$result = $db->query($sql))
    {
        die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
    }
}
```

Comment: Couple of points here; 1) you don't really need to escape the strings when you know they're already safe. 2) This will generate 1000 different statements on the MySQL server. Some environments may have limits restricting this

Comment: @Phil. Thank you friend for the suggestions. Since I use escape string for all queries in my projects, I added it here too without noticing the point you mentioned. :)

Comment: Well, it's not going to hurt anything leaving it in ;)

Answer (score -2):

```
$email = uniqid();
$sql .= "('".$id1[$i]."','".$email."@gmail.com','male', 'Computer Science'),";
```